# How to call ajax when change value cell in dxdatagrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, dx-data-grid

dxDataGrid: How can I call Ajax inside `setCellValue()`. My goal is that after changing the value of a cell, I will call Ajax again to get the value and reset it for other cells.
but it didn't work!! response value was returned but newData was not implemented

I have done it as follows:

```
setCellValue: function(newData, value, currentRowData) {
    newData.supplies = value;
    let dataSupp = value.split(' &*& ');
    newData.supplies_code = dataSupp[0]
    newData.supplies_unit = dataSupp[2]
    let sales = $('#sales').val();
    let expected_revenue = $('#expected_revenue').val();
    let order_use_from = $('#order_use_from').val();
    let order_use_to = $('#order_use_to').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('admin.shopping-request.per-mil') }}",
        data: {
            sales: sales,
            expected_revenue: expected_revenue,
            order_use_from: order_use_from,
            order_use_to: order_use_to,
            dataSupp: dataSupp
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            newData.per_mil = response;
        }
    });
}
```

I expect new data to be set when the Ajax is done.
Can someone tell me a reasonable solution? Thank you everyone for your interest

Comment: use `cellVlue()` method to set: https://js.devexpress.com/React/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Methods/#cellValuerowIndex_visibleColumnIndex

Comment: I don't know its row and column number

Comment: currentRowData.<cellname> = new value

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work as i expected: currentRowData.per_mil = response